# Cant call a function multiple times in Redis Lua script

Tags: lua, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a function inside Redis Lua script. If I call the function once everything runs smooth. But if I call the function multiple times I get an error "ERR Protocol error: expected '$', got ' '"

```
var doesExist6 = db.ScriptEvaluate(@" local userName = KEYS[1]


                                                    local function mysplit(inputstr, sep)
                                                            if sep == nil then
                                                                    sep = '%s'
                                                            end
                                                            local t={}  
                                                            local i=1
                                                            for str in string.gmatch(inputstr, '([^'..sep..']+)') do
                                                                    t[i] = str
                                                                    i = i + 1
                                                            end
                                                            return t
                                                    end


                                                    local abc = {}
                                                        abc = mysplit(userName, ':')
                                                        for k = 1, #abc, 1
                                                        do
                                                            print (abc[k])
                                                        end

                                                        local xyz = {}
                                                        xyz = mysplit(userName, ':')
                                                        for k = 1, #xyz, 1
                                                        do
                                                            print (xyz[k])
                                                        end

                                                        return xyz[1]..abc[2]",

            new RedisKey[] { "UserDetails:" + "DummyUser" });
```

If I call the function mysplit() only once to populate the table 'abc' then everything runs smooth but if I call the function mysplit() second time to populate the table xyz it throws an error "ERR Protocol error: expected '$', got ' '".

What could be the possible reason? Is it that Redis does not allow functions inside Lua scripts?

Comment: your code works fine for me actually

Comment: I modified the code according to your suggestion. In fact, commented out the entire section and have kept only the function calls. Still, I am getting the same error.

Comment: I ran your code from the python client and it just worked, prints and all

Comment: The code works; I have verified it by running it in SciTE IDE (IDE for Lua scripting for Windows environment) . I am getting the error in client. The client in my case is StackExchange.Redis for the .Net environment.

Comment: Strangely it works now. The Error seems quite generic in nature. It now gives me the same error but for some other reason. [Error Messge -- "ERR Protocol error: expected '$', got ' '".]

Comment: I have no idea about what library you use. But seems it problem on redis protocol level. '$' is marker of bulk string. So problem may be in client library.

Comment: Running it locally with SE.Redis it works fine; is this happening repeatedly?

Comment: Does not happen repeatedly. But occurs frequently. Cant predict when and also unable to find the exact cause.