# StackExchange.Redis Lua script error in for loop

Tags: lua, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am facing a problem with the Lua script (please find it below) in the StackExchange.Redis. 
I have dissected the code and got all of it working except for the last loop. 
I get the following as error -- ERR Protocol error: expected '$', got ' '
The error message is quite generic in nature, as it gives me the same error message for different types of errors.
Can someone help me to figure out the problem?

```
var doesExist = (bool)db.ScriptEvaluate(@" 
                                        local function isDateInRange(DateStart, DateEnd, GivenDate)
                                            if (GivenDate > DateStart and GivenDate < DateEnd)
                                            then
                                                return(true)
                                            else
                                            return(false)
                                        end
                                    end

                                    --Fetch User's Category's StartDate and EndDate
                                    local function IsCategoryDateValid()
                                    local givenDate, DateStart, DateEnd

                                    GivenDate = '2017-01-09'
                                    StartDate = '2015-01-01'
                                    EndDate = '2018-01-01'

                                    local isDateValid
                                    isDateValid = isDateInRange(StartDate, EndDate, GivenDate)
                                    return(isDateValid)
                                    end

                                    -- Pass User, UserCategory and UserCategoryItem as parameters
                                    local userNameKey = 'UserDetails:Invincible'
                                    local userCategoryKey = 'UserCategories:Book'
                                    local userCategoryItemKey = 'UserCategoryItems:Harry-Potter'

                                    local userNameKeySplit = {}
                                    local a = 1
                                    for i in string.gmatch(userNameKey, '([^'..':'..']+)') do
                                      userNameKeySplit[a] = i
                                      a = a + 1
                                    end
                                    local userName = userNameKeySplit[2]


                                    local userCategoryKeySplit = {}
                                    local b = 1
                                    for j in string.gmatch(userCategoryKey, '([^'..':'..']+)') do
                                      userCategoryKeySplit[b] = j
                                      b = b + 1
                                    end
                                    local userCategory = userCategoryKeySplit[2]



                                    local userCategoryItemKeySplit = {}
                                    local c = 1
                                    for k in string.gmatch(userCategoryItemKey, '([^'..':'..']+)') do
                                      userCategoryItemKeySplit[c] = k
                                      c = c + 1
                                    end
                                    local userCategoryItem = userCategoryItemKeySplit[2]


                                    -- Fetch Users, UserCategories and UserCategoryItems from the Redis DB
                                    local userData = {'Invincible', 'User1', 'User2', 'User3'}
                                    local userCategoryData = {'Book', 'Movie', 'Journals'}
                                    local userCategoryItemData = {'Hardy-Boys', 'Harry-Potter', 'Shawshank-Redemption', 'The-Terminal'}

                                    local msg


                                    for i=1,#userData,1
                                            do
                                                if(userData[i] == userName)
                                                then
                                                    for j=1,#userCategoryData,1
                                                    do
                                                        if(userCategoryData[j] == userCategory)
                                                        then
                                                            msg = true
                                                        break
                                                        else
                                                            msg = false
                                                        end
                                                    end             
                                                break
                                                else
                                                    msg = false
                                                    break
                                                end
                                            end


                                    return msg





                                    ",

            new RedisKey[] { "UserDetails:" + "Invincible", "UserCategories:" + "Book", "UserCategoryItems:" + "Harry-Potter" });
```

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335197/cant-call-a-function-multiple-times-in-redis-lua-script