# Lua script error when run from stackexchange.redis

Tags: lua, redis, stackexchange.redis

We have a lengthy lua script. Please find it below after the problem description.

The logic of the script is to return true/false if all the 3 parameters match (UserName, UserCategory, UserCategoryItem)

The first part of the script splits the RedisKeys to fetch the UserName, UserCategory, UserCategoryItem.  There is also a random function to test if ‘functions’ works in the Redis lua script. It works.

The second part of the script compares this values against the values in the Database. The values are hard-coded in the script. If all the values match it returns true else it returns false.

The two scripts run perfect when ran individually. But they throw an error when run together.

**ISSUE/PROBLEM**

All the three scripts run perfectly when run in an IDE. I use the SciTE IDE (an IDE for Lua for Windows envrionment)

The script creates an issue when  run from the Stackexchange.Redis client.

The first two parts of the script (Part One and Part Two) run perfectly from the Stackexchange.Redis. It is only when they are combined in the third script (Part Three) does it throw an error. 
As the error is generic in nature hence I am not able to further investigate the issue.

I have divided the script in Three parts. The final script combines the first two scripts.

```
var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
var db = redis.GetDatabase();

//PART ONE OF THE SCRIPT

            var doesExist1 = (string)db.ScriptEvaluate(@" 
 local function isDateInRange(DateStart, DateEnd, GivenDate)
    if (GivenDate > DateStart and GivenDate < DateEnd)
    then
        return(true)
    else
        return(false)
    end
end

--Fetch User's Category's StartDate and EndDate
local function IsCategoryDateValid()
local givenDate, DateStart, DateEnd

GivenDate = '2017-01-09'
StartDate = '2015-01-01'
EndDate = '2018-01-01'

local isDateValid
isDateValid = isDateInRange(StartDate, EndDate, GivenDate)
return(isDateValid)
end

-- Pass User, UserCategory and UserCategoryItem as parameters
local userNameKey = 'UserDetails:DummyName'
local userCategoryKey = 'UserCategories:Book'
local userCategoryItemKey = 'UserCategoryItems:Harry-Potter'

local userNameKeySplit = {}
local a = 1
for i in string.gmatch(userNameKey, '([^'..':'..']+)') do
  userNameKeySplit[a] = i
  a = a + 1
end
local userName = userNameKeySplit[2]


local userCategoryKeySplit = {}
local b = 1
for j in string.gmatch(userCategoryKey, '([^'..':'..']+)') do
  userCategoryKeySplit[b] = j
  b = b + 1
end
local userCategory = userCategoryKeySplit[2]



local userCategoryItemKeySplit = {}
local c = 1
for k in string.gmatch(userCategoryItemKey, '([^'..':'..']+)') do
  userCategoryItemKeySplit[c] = k
  c = c + 1
end
local userCategoryItem = userCategoryItemKeySplit[2]

return(userName..' '..userCategory..' '..userCategoryItem)

",

                new RedisKey[] { "UserCategoryItemNames:" + userModel.UserId });


//PART TWO OF THE SCRIPT

            var doesExist2 = (bool)db.ScriptEvaluate(@" 
local userName = 'DummyName'
local userCategory = 'Book'
local userCategoryItem = 'Harry-Potter'

-- Fetch Users, UserCategories and UserCategoryItems from the Redis DB
local userData = {'DummyName', 'User1', 'User2', 'User3'}
local userCategoryData = {'Book', 'Movie', 'Journals'}
local userCategoryItemData = {'Hardy-Boys', 'Harry-Potter', 'Shawshank-Redemption', 'The-Terminal'}

local msg
-- Loop through the fetched values and compare them with parameters; if all the parameters are found return true else return false
for i=1,#userData,1
        do
            if(userData[i] == userName)
            then
                for i=1,#userCategoryData,1
                do
                    if(userCategoryData[i] == userCategory)
                    then
                        for i=1,#userCategoryItemData,1
                        do
                            if(userCategoryItemData[i] == userCategoryItem)
                            then
                                msg = true
                            break
                            else
                                msg = false
                            end
                        end
                    break
                    else
                        msg = false
                    end
                end
            break
            else
                msg = false
                break
            end
        end



return(msg)

//PART ONE & TWO COMBINED OF THE SCRIPT

                                        ",

                new RedisKey[] { "UserDetails:" + "DummyName", "UserCategories:" + "Book", "UserCategoryItems:" + "Harry-Potter" });

            var doesExist3 = (bool)db.ScriptEvaluate(@" 

local function isDateInRange(DateStart, DateEnd, GivenDate)
    if (GivenDate > DateStart and GivenDate < DateEnd)
    then
        return(true)
    else
        return(false)
    end
end

--Fetch User's Category's StartDate and EndDate
local function IsCategoryDateValid()
local givenDate, DateStart, DateEnd

GivenDate = '2017-01-09'
StartDate = '2015-01-01'
EndDate = '2018-01-01'

local isDateValid
isDateValid = isDateInRange(StartDate, EndDate, GivenDate)
return(isDateValid)
end

-- Pass User, UserCategory and UserCategoryItem as parameters
local userNameKey = 'UserDetails:DummyName'
local userCategoryKey = 'UserCategories:Book'
local userCategoryItemKey = 'UserCategoryItems:Harry-Potter'

local userNameKeySplit = {}
local a = 1
for i in string.gmatch(userNameKey, '([^'..':'..']+)') do
  userNameKeySplit[a] = i
  a = a + 1
end
local userName = userNameKeySplit[2]


local userCategoryKeySplit = {}
local b = 1
for j in string.gmatch(userCategoryKey, '([^'..':'..']+)') do
  userCategoryKeySplit[b] = j
  b = b + 1
end
local userCategory = userCategoryKeySplit[2]



local userCategoryItemKeySplit = {}
local c = 1
for k in string.gmatch(userCategoryItemKey, '([^'..':'..']+)') do
  userCategoryItemKeySplit[c] = k
  c = c + 1
end
local userCategoryItem = userCategoryItemKeySplit[2]

-- Fetch Users, UserCategories and UserCategoryItems from the Redis DB
local userData = {'DummyName', 'User1', 'User2', 'User3'}
local userCategoryData = {'Book', 'Movie', 'Journals'}
local userCategoryItemData = {'Hardy-Boys', 'Harry-Potter', 'Shawshank-Redemption', 'The-Terminal'}

local msg
-- Loop through the fetched values and compare them with parameters; if all the parameters are found return true else return false
for i=1,#userData,1
        do
            if(userData[i] == userName)
            then
                for i=1,#userCategoryData,1
                do
                    if(userCategoryData[i] == userCategory)
                    then
                        for i=1,#userCategoryItemData,1
                        do
                            if(userCategoryItemData[i] == userCategoryItem)
                            then
                                msg = true
                            break
                            else
                                msg = false
                            end
                        end
                    break
                    else
                        msg = false
                    end
                end
            break
            else
                msg = false
                break
            end
        end



return(msg)

                                        ",

                new RedisKey[] { "UserDetails:" + "DummyName", "UserCategories:" + "Book", "UserCategoryItems:" + "Harry-Potter" });
```

Thank you for your patience and reading this much. I hope I have clarified the problem in detail. Please provide some help in solving the issue. Thank you.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: The error message is "ERR Protocol error: expected '$', got ' ' " .. Also I get this error when I use a pre-release version of stackexchange.redis from Nuget, as this is the version that works with .Net Core (Asp.Net 5). When I try to run the script from .Net 4.5 using the stable version of Stackexchange.redis I get the error sporadically i.e sometimes the code runs with the error and sometimes returns 'eof expected' error.

Comment: I see a lot of questions on StackExchange about the exact same error lately. In al cases (that I remember) it happened when they call a Lua function twice or use a for-loop.

Comment: Yeah. Correct. I was not clear with the problem and hence ended up creating multiple questions for the problem. In this question I have added everything possible and unified it. I apologize if that has caused inconvenience to anybody.

Comment: You could've edited your old question. To be fair, I don't even remember your name, but I'm pretty sure there were other people with similar stuff. _(including totally different code snippets)_

Comment: These two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337330/stackexchange-redis-lua-script-error-in-for-loop, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335197/cant-call-a-function-multiple-times-in-redis-lua-script